# Type inference similar to hindley milner in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I was recently intrigued by the Hindley Milner algorithm (for type inference) and decided to implement it in python. After implementing it, I got the feeling that the implementation was incorrect. I also felt that it wasn't very pythonic, and was sort of inefficient. Here is my code (it isn't as long as it looks-- there is just a lot of documentation):

**ie_ast.py**

```py
class InferenceError(Exception): pass
class Type: pass
class Node: pass


class Int(Type, Node):
    def __init__(self, number):
        """A basic integer node

        Args:
            number: a integer
        """
        self.number = number

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        return "int"


class Float(Type, Node):
    def __init__(self, number):
        """A basic float node

        Args:
            number: a float
        """
        self.number = number

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        return "float"


class String(Type, Node):
    def __init__(self, string):
        """A basic string node

        Args:
            string: a string
        """
        self.string = string

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        return "string"


class Bool(Type, Node):
    def __init__(self, _bool):
        """A basic boolean node

        Args:
            _bool: a boolean
        """
        self._bool = _bool

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        return "bool"


class Void(Type, Node):
    def __init__(self):
        """No type"""

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        return "void"

class Wildcard(Type, Node):
    def __init__(self):
        """Genric type (for return smts)"""

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        return "wildcard"


class Unknown(Type, Node):
    def __init__(self):
        """A currently unknow type"""

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        return "unknown"


class Ident(Node):
    def __init__(self, name):
        """An identifer

        Args:
            name: a name
        """
        self.name = name
        self.type = Unknown()

    def annotate_type(self, _type):
        self.type = _type

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type


class BinOp(Node):
    def __init__(self, left, op, right):
        """A binary operation node

        Args:
            left: the left hand side node
            op: the opertaion (+/-/*//)
            right: the right hand side node
        """
        self.left = left
        self.op = op
        self.right = right
        self.type = Unknown()

    def annotate_type(self, _type):
        self.type = _type

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type


class IfElse(Node):
    def __init__(self, condition, if_program, else_program):
        """A if-else node

        Args:
            condition: a Bool of true/false
            if_program: what to do if the condition evaluates as true
            else_program: what to do if the condition evaluates as false
        """
        self.condition = condition
        self.if_program = if_program
        self.else_program = else_program
        self.if_program_type = Unknown()
        self.else_program_type = Unknown()
        self.type = Unknown()

    def annotate_if_program_type(self, _type):
        self.if_program_type = _type

    def annotate_else_program_type(self, _type):
        self.else_program_type = _type

    def get_if_program_type(self):
        return self.if_program_type

    def get_else_program_type(self):
        return self.else_program_type

    def annotate_type(self, _type):
        self.type = _type

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type


class VarDef(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        """A variable node node

        Args:
            name: the variable's name
            value: the variable's value
        """
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.type = Unknown()

    def annotate_type(self, _type):
        self.type = _type

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type


class FuncDef(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, args, program):
        """A function node

        Args:
            name: the function's name
            args: the function's arguments of an unknown type
            program: the function's program
        """
        self.name = name
        self.args = args
        self.program = program
        self.type = Unknown()

    def annotate_type(self, _type):
        self.type = _type

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type


class FuncCall(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, args):
        """A function call node

        Args:
            name: the function's name
            args: the function's arguments
        """
        self.name = name
        self.args = args
        self.type = Unknown() if self.name.name != "return" else Wildcard()

    def annotate_type(self, _type):
        self.type = _type

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type
```

**ie.py**

```py
from ie_ast import *

class InferenceEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        """Builds a type table for a supplied ast"""
        # built in functions
        self.built_ins = ["println", "return"]

    def infer(self, node_list, type_table, actual_node_list):
        """Inference machinery

           Args:
                node_list: a list of nodes
                type_table: the table to read and write types
                actual_node_list: None if it node_list is the base program.
                    If it is not None, it must the base_program

            Returns:
                An annotated node_list
        """
        if actual_node_list is None:
            actual_node_list = node_list

        for node in node_list:
            if isinstance(node, Ident):
                self.infer_ident(node, type_table, actual_node_list)
            elif isinstance(node, BinOp):
                self.infer_bin_op(node, type_table, actual_node_list)
            elif isinstance(node, IfElse):
                self.infer_if_else(node, type_table, actual_node_list)
            elif isinstance(node, VarDef):
                self.infer_var_def(node, type_table, actual_node_list)
            elif isinstance(node, FuncDef):
                self.infer_func_def(node, type_table, actual_node_list)
            elif isinstance(node, FuncCall):
                self.infer_func_call(node, type_table, actual_node_list)
            elif isinstance(node, Int):
                # int does not need to be type checked because it is
                # a basic type, and can't be reduced
                pass
            elif isinstance(node, Float):
                # float does not need to be type checked because it is
                # a basic type, and can't be reduced
                pass
            elif isinstance(node, String):
                # string does not need to be type checked because it is
                # a basic type, and can't be reduced
                pass
            elif isinstance(node, Bool):
                # bool does not need to be type checked because it is
                # a basic type, and can't be reduced
                pass
        return node_list

    def infer_ident(self, node, type_table, node_list):
        """Gets the type of any identifier

           Args:
                node: the ident node
                type_table: the table to read and write types
                actual_node_list: the base program

            Returns:
                An annotated ident
        """
        node.annotate_type(type_table[node.name])

    def infer_bin_op(self, node, type_table, node_list):
        """Infers the type of any binop (+/-/*//)

           Args:
                node: the binop node
                type_table: the table to read and write types
                actual_node_list: the base program

            Returns:
                An annotated binop node
        """
        left_type = self.infer([node.left], type_table,
                               node_list)[0].get_type()
        right_type = self.infer([node.right], type_table,
                                node_list)[0].get_type()

        # check if the left type and right type are not the same
        if type(left_type) is not type(right_type):
            raise InferenceError("incompatible types")

        node.annotate_type(left_type)

    def infer_if_else(self, node, type_table, node_list):
        """Infers the type of a if-else smt (and runs type checks)

           Args:
                node: an if-else node
                type_table: the table to read and write types
                actual_node_list: the base program

            Returns:
                An annotated (and type checked) if-else node
        """
        condition_type = self.infer([node.condition], type_table,
                                    node_list)[0].get_type()

        # makes sure that the condition's type is bool
        if not isinstance(condition_type, Bool):
            raise InferenceError(
                "expected if-else condition to be of type bool")

        # look for returns statements in the if program
        # this is done to make sure all of them return the
        # same type
        if_ret_types = self.look_for_return_smts(node.if_program, self,
                                                 type_table)
        if if_ret_types:
            if not len(set(map(type, if_ret_types))) == 1:
                raise InferenceError(
                    "if program has multiple return statements that don't return the same thing"
                )
            node.if_program_type = if_ret_types[0]
        else:
            node.if_program_type = Void()

        # look for returns statements in the else program
        # this is done to make sure all of them return the
        # same type
        else_ret_types = self.look_for_return_smts(node.else_program, self,
                                                   type_table)
        if else_ret_types:
            if not len(set(map(type, else_ret_types))) == 1:
                raise InferenceError(
                    "else program has multiple return statements that don't return the same thing"
                )
            node.else_program_type = else_ret_types[0]
        else:
            node.else_program_type = Void()

        # can't say the if and else statement's program don't return
        # the same type if one of them is unknown
        if type(node.if_program_type) is not type(
                node.else_program_type) and not isinstance(
                    node.if_program_type, Unknown) and not isinstance(
                        node.else_program_type, Unknown):
            raise InferenceError(
                "if statement and else statement return different types")

        node.annotate_type(
            node.if_program_type if not isinstance(
                node.if_program_type, Unknown) else node.else_program_type)

    def infer_var_def(self, node, type_table, node_list):
        """Gets the type of any variable

           Args:
                node: a vardef node
                type_table: the table to read and write types
                actual_node_list: the base program

            Returns:
                An annotated vardef node
        """
        var_type = self.infer([node.value], type_table,
                              node_list)[0].get_type()
        type_table[node.name.name] = var_type
        node.annotate_type(var_type)

    def infer_func_def(self, node, type_table, node_list, skip_args=False):
        """Attempts to get the type of a function upon definition

           Args:
                node: a funcdef node
                type_table: the table to read and write types
                actual_node_list: the base program

            Returns:
                An (maybe almost) annotated funcdef node
        """
        # inserts itself into the type table for when
        # it is called
        type_table[node.name.name] = node

        if not skip_args:
            for arg in node.args:
                type_table[arg.name] = Unknown()
                arg.annotate_type(Unknown())

        # gets the program's node annotated with their respective types
        node.program = self.infer(node.program, type_table, node_list)
        return_types = self.look_for_return_smts(node.program, self,
                                                 type_table)

        # removes all the returns that have a type of unknown
        filtered_rets = [
            elm for elm in return_types if not isinstance(elm, Unknown)
        ]

        # checks is the function's program has return statements
        # that don't return the same type
        if filtered_rets:
            if not len(set(map(type, filtered_rets))) == 1:
                raise InferenceError(
                    "function has return statements with incompatible types")
            node.annotate_type(filtered_rets[0])
        else:
            node.annotate_type(Void())

        if skip_args:
            return node

    def infer_func_call(self, node, type_table, node_list):
        """Infers the type of a function, intern getting its own type

           Args:
                node: a funccall node
                type_table: the table to read and write types
                actual_node_list: the base program

            Returns:
                An annotated funccall node
        """
        if node.name.name not in self.built_ins:
            # get the function previously inserted into the type table
            func = type_table[node.name.name]

            # annotate the function's args with the types of the
            # arguments supplied to the function call
            for arg, call_arg in zip(func.args, node.args):
                arg_type = self.infer([call_arg], type_table,
                                      node_list)[0].get_type()
                type_table[arg.name] = arg_type
                arg.annotate_type(arg_type)

            # now that we know the args types we can completely
            # infer the function's program's types, thus
            # getting the function's type
            changed_func = self.infer_func_def(func, type_table, node_list,
                                               True)
            node.annotate_type(changed_func.get_type())
            type_table[node.name.name] = changed_func
            node_list[node_list.index(func)] = changed_func
        else:
            # annotate the node with the type of its argument
            node.annotate_type(
                self.infer(node.args, type_table, node_list)[0].get_type())

    def look_for_return_smts(self, program, ie, type_table):
        """Looks for return smts in a given program

           Args:
                program: the program to search in
                ie: an inference engine
                type_table: the table to read and write types

            Returns:
                All the return smt type in a given program
        """
        return_smts = []
        for program_node in program:
            if isinstance(program_node,
                          FuncCall) and program_node.name.name == "return":
                # insert into the return smts list the type of the argument
                return_smts.append(
                    ie.infer(program_node.args, type_table,
                             None)[0].get_type())
            elif isinstance(program_node, IfElse):
                return_smts.extend(
                    ie.infer(
                        self.look_for_return_smts(program_node.if_program, ie,
                                                  type_table), type_table,
                        None))
                return_smts.extend(
                    ie.infer(
                        self.look_for_return_smts(program_node.else_program,
                                                  ie, type_table), type_table,
                        None))

        return return_smts
```

**main.py**

```
from ie import InferenceEngine
from ie_ast import *

# example usage
"""
foo = 123 + 123
foobar = True
if foobar:
    pi
else:
    3.1415

println(foo)
def bar(a, b, c):
    baz = foobar
    if foobar:
        if false:
            return a + b
        else:
            return c + b
    else:
        if true:
            return 123
        else:
            return 321
abc = bar(12.2, 123321, foo) * foo / 456
"""
ie = InferenceEngine()
type_table = {}
program = [
    VarDef(Ident("foo"), BinOp(Int("123"), "+", Int("123"))),
    VarDef(Ident("foobar"), Bool("true")),
    IfElse(Ident("foobar"), [String("pi")], [Float("3.1415")]),
    FuncCall(Ident("println"), [Ident("foo")]),
    FuncDef(
        Ident("bar"),
        [Ident("a"), Ident("b"), Ident("c")], [
            VarDef(Ident("baz"), Ident("foobar")),
            IfElse(
                Ident("foobar"), [
                    IfElse(
                        Bool("false"), [
                            FuncCall(
                                Ident("return"),
                                [BinOp(Ident("a"), "+", Ident("b"))])
                        ], [
                            FuncCall(
                                Ident("return"),
                                [BinOp(Ident("c"), "+", Ident("b"))])
                        ])
                ], [
                    IfElse(
                        Bool("true"),
                        [FuncCall(Ident("return"), [Int("123")])],
                        [FuncCall(Ident("return"), [Int("321")])])
                ])
        ]),
    VarDef(
        Ident("abc"),
        BinOp(
            FuncCall(
                Ident("bar"),
                [Int("12.12"), Int("123321"),
                 Ident("foo")]), "*", BinOp(Ident("foo"), "/", Int("456")))),
]

infered = ie.infer(program, type_table, None)

# print out the type table
print("type table:")
print({k: v.get_type().show() for k, v in type_table.items()})
```

Does this follow the hindley milner algorithm, and is there some way I could make it better?

Comment: Maybe the files could have been better named!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first file could be a lot shorter if you made the `Type` class slightly more than a useless empty namespace:

```
class Type:
    name = None

    def get_type(self):
        return self

    def show(self):
        if self.name is None:
            raise NotImplementedError
        return self.name
```

Then all your other types get shorter:

```
class Int(Type, Node):
     """A basic integer node"""
    name = "int"

    def __init__(self, number):
        """A basic integer node

        Args:
            number: an integer
        """
        self.number = number
```

Especially the ones that don't need any argument in the constructor:

```
class Void(Type, Node):
    """No type"""
    name = "void"
```

It could be argued that the `show` method should be called `__str__` or `__repr__`, making them [magic methods](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/), depending on your need.

Similarly for `Node`:

```
class Node:

    def annotate_type(self, _type):
        self.type = _type

    def get_type(self):
        return self.type
```

At this point you could also realize that there is no need to have these getters and setters in the first place. [In Python using a plain attribute is usually preferred](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php). You can always start with an attribute and add getters and setters if you need them (i.e. if they do more than just getting and setting an attribute) by using `property`.